# select output colospace in ffmpeg's stagefright codec

Tags: android, ffmpeg, stagefright

I'm new here so first of all, i'd like to say that this is an awesome comunity :-). Well, let's start with my question.

Currently, I'm working with an embbeded systems (freescale imx6 and exynos 4412 based processors). The main idea is to develop a voip app with HD video (1080p) for Android. The video is captured via H264 hardware webcam (logitech c920). Until now, I'm able to use the ffmpeg's libstagefright codec, it works really fine and faster but I have the problem that lots of people have. "The colorspace conversion".

As I can see in the code,

```
outFormat = (*s->decoder)->getFormat();
outFormat->findInt32(kKeyColorFormat, &colorFormat);
```

We can get the output colorspace format, but my question is:

Could I define other output colorspace format? How?

If I were able to perform this task via stagefright (because the vendors provides the hardware accel by this way) I could overcome the colorspace conversion time penalty when I perform this task via OpenGL.

Thank you!

Regards

Comment: @Javier.. To give a better answer, it would help if you could confirm if you have the following accesses (1) Access to entire android tree and the ability to modify the same, specifically not just `OMXCodec`, but also `SurfaceFlinger` and related modules + `HwComposer` + `hardware` modules. (2) If the decoder's output format is `X`, can your underlying display sub-system i.e. `SurfaceFlinger` + `HwComposer` directly work on this format or will there always be a cost of color conversion?